# Videos saved on Firebase storage don't work on phone's browser

Tags: html5-video, firebase-storage

I am storing my videos on Firebase Storage. The videos work perfectly fine in the browser when I use a laptop or desktop computer. However, they do not function properly when accessed through the browser on a mobile phone.
Here is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaFD2.png)

Initially, I thought the issue might be due to the video tag I used in the project. However, when I checked directly using the URL of the video located in the Firebase console, the result I received was a black screen. The video's duration was displayed accurately in seconds, but the visuals did not play.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5n8P.png)

What is the cause of this issue? Please assist me.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: But even with that, it'll be unlikely that someone can help with the limited information provided. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example). While this requires extra effort in your part, following the guidance in there will give you a much better chance that someone can help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can try to decrease the resolution and the frame rate of your videos. 1920 px by 1080 px and 30 frames per second solved the problem for me.